# Electron not loading web application with full functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, cross-platform, electron

I tried loading a web application in electron using window.loadurl and as webview in html. Application is displaying, but with different errors like:

```
$ jquery not defined
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
```

I tried different methods and finally get rid off '$ jquery not defined' error. 
Why electron is not acting as a browser. This application is working fine on all browsers. 
How can I load this web application to my electron with functionalities. 
My web application is :

> www.mcgeoautomation.com

My index.js file is:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
var path=require('path');


const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var mainWindow;

app.on('ready',function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024, 
        height: 768,
        backgroundColor: '#2e2c29',
        show:false,
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/webView.html`);
    mainWindow.maximize(true);
    // mainWindow.setMenu(null);
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show',()=>{
        mainWindow.show()
    })

    mainWindow.on('close', (e)=>{

        app.quit();
    });
});
```

package.json file:

```
`{
  "name": "crushmate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.9",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13"
  }
}`
```

Please help...
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Electron doesn't handle `jQuery` the same as a regular browser does. You have to essentially inject it into the `webview`. Can't test this right now but should get you on the way to it working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery injection into webview preload</title>
  </head>
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <webview id="webview" preload="./preload.js" src="http://www.mcgeoautomation.com" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"></webview>
    <script>
      // need to have a script tag make webview work even if you don't plan to use it...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

preload.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

Comment: With this method, I can now easily sign in. Initially on login form it was showing '$ jquery undefined' , but now it is clear. But all other problems are still there. No dropdowns working. Button clicks are not working. Console not showing any errors now. @kemotoe

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and deativating `nodeIntegration` solved it for me.
Just add following code when creating a `BrowserWindow`:

```
webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false
}
```

(The used electron version is "11.2.0")